# Firestore indexes error `__name__ only indexes are not supported`

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, indexing

I am trying to deploy firestore indexes and I am getting the error `__name__ only indexes are not supported`.

I checked the DESCENDING indexes that are newly added and they seem to be fine. There are a bunch of composite indexes, I am not sure which one is causing the error.

What are the potential causes for this error?

Comment: Can you share your index file?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Unfortunately, I cannot do it. And there are a lot of indexes.

Comment: I deployed the indexes again and there were no issues. Looks like it was an intermittent problem. But still it would be great to know, what to look for when the deployment fails with these kind of errors.

Answer (score 1):

To find the specific index that is causing the issue try this:

delete 1/2 of your indexes and run deploy. If you get the error again, repeat...

if you don't get the error, deploy the half you deleted, and repeat.

eventually you will get the specific index that is causing the error